# Presented UINavigationController tint color not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

```
    MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc] init];
vc.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[nc.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self presentViewController:nc animated:true completion:^{}];
```

The navigation bar is black. I present this from a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller which is created in my App Delegate. In my ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I can control the color of the navigation controllers there.

Why is this navigation controller tint bar black?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I would suggest you to use this if all of your NavigationBars are the same color. **Appearance** property of an object sets uniformity on the function you apply on it.

Comment: I tried that. I'll give it a shot again and remove all other tint colors.

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to make custom class for UINavigationBar

.h

```
@interface CustomUINavigationBar : UINavigationBar {

}

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation CustomUINavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.023 green:0.14 blue:0.478 alpha:1];// for example
    self.tintColor = color;

}

@end
```

Also you can try to insert the below code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: of AppDelegate.m

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `iOS7` you have to use `barTintColor` property

```
[nc.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

instead of

```
[nc.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```